# Looking for a term : end of song n is the beginning of song n+1

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a term describing the fact that, on a music album, the end of a song is the beginning of the next one, which gives the impression that there is no cut between the two songs.

I'm pretty sure a special term exists and I used to hear it, though I'm not 100 % sure...

Examples : between *Perfect* and *Daphne Descends* on The Smashing Pumpkins' album *Adore*, or between *Links 2-3-4* and *Sonne* on Rammstein's album *Mutter*.

Comment: Rammstein 4 ever \m/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called a [segue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segue#In_music), from the Italian *segue* - "follows", generally meaning a smooth transition.

Wikipedia also mentions that some album notations distinguish track listings through the use of symbols, such as a `>`, `→`, or `/` to indicate songs that flow seamlessly.

Comment: This term doesn't ring a bell to me at all, but it seems pretty clear that, according to Wikipedia's "Famous examples in rock music" in the Segue article, it is the correct word I was looking for ! Thank you :)

Comment: If the transition is a contrasting section it might serve as a *bridge* between songs.

Comment: And it's pronounced "seg-way" with two syllables.

Comment: "Segue" covers those situations, as in an opera where one number follows another with no dialogue or action in between, though the first number comes to a definite end, and there may be time for the audience to applaud it. Terms for the situation where the first flows seamlessly into the second, without missing a beat, include "dead segue" and "segue as one". The score may use the musical indication "attacca".

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly thinking of the term **medley** which is two or more distinctly different songs being performed as a single song, where each piece transitions smoothly into the next.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medley

One of the most famous medleys in recorded music is the Beatles' *Abbey Road* medley, which consists of eight short songs by Lennon and McCartney, performed without a break between them.

https://songstoriesmatter.com/story-behind-abbey-road-medley-the-beatles/